# Keep div loaded when navigating

Tags: angular

I have a div (NewCall) that I want to keep open when the user navigates between pages in my SPA.

The div is in my layout page, and is loaded on user click, but when I navigate somewhere else the div closes.

I'm currently using a routerLink to load the component for the div, and I'm pretty sure that's why is closing when navigating elsewhere, but I'm not sure what to use instead.

If anyone is familiar with SalesForce, they do exactly what I'm wanting with their call logging feature.

> ```
>     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
>         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
>             <li>
>                 <a style="padding-top: 20px" [routerLink]="['NewCall']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
>             </li>
>             <li>
>                 <p class="navbar-text">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>
>             </li>
>         </ul>
>     </div>
> ...
> <div id="Call" #call>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the `div` need to be routable? I.e. does it need to have a URL and be navigated to by the URL?

If not, you could simply add an `*ngIf` on the `div` and show it on a user click in the menu bar.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a style="padding-top: 20px" (click)="setCallSectionVisible()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <p class="navbar-text">Hello, @User.Identity.Name!</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
...
<div id="Call" *ngIf="callSectionVisible" #call>
</div>
```

Component code:

```
setCallSectionVisible() {
    this.callSectionVisible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a cookie on user click, and on each subsequent page load check if that cookie exists. If so, show the NewCall div.